# How to hide the Reviews tab when there are no reviews

Tags: product, magento2.4

I am using Reviews in the project. We have the form itself hidden, the only thing we display is a list of reviews generated from the admin panel. I would like to be able to hide the `Reviews` tab when there are no reviews, i.e. `.review-list` is empty. How and where can I do this? Unfortunately, the custom written script runs much earlier by which the tab does not want to hide for me. Please help, thank you.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

To hide the Reviews tab when there are no reviews in Magento 2, you can create a plugin to modify the product view block and check if the review list is empty. If it is, then hide the tab. Here's how you can do it:

1. Create a plugin for the product view block. In your custom module's directory, create a directory named **Plugin** and create a file named **ProductViewBlock.php** inside the **Plugin** directory.
2. Add the following code in **ProductViewBlock.php**:

```
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View;

class ProductViewBlock
{
    public function afterToHtml(View $subject, $result)
    {
        $reviewsBlock = $subject->getChildBlock('reviews');
        if (!$reviewsBlock || !$reviewsBlock->getReviewsCollection()->getSize()) {
            $result = str_replace('data-role="reviews-tab"', 'style="display:none;"', $result);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

3. Register the plugin in the **etc/frontend/di.xml** file of your custom module:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View">
    <plugin name="hide_reviews_tab" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\ProductViewBlock" />
</type>
```

4. Clear the cache and check the product view page. The Reviews tab should now be hidden if there are no reviews.

Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry, but your code unfortunately does not work. Nothing happens on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code in your layout file.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.review">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="reviews" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">reviews</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Review/product/view/review</item>
                        <item name="displayIfEmpty" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

I add one condition attribute in layout file can you check it is working or not.

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Sorry, but your code unfortunately does not work. Nothing happens on the page.